Number of copies of a fundamental domain for $\Gamma_0(q)/\{\pm1\} $ needed to cover a region $P(Y) = \{z \mid \Im z > Y, \Re(z) \in ]0,1] \}$ ($Y>0$)
I've been struggling on a claim in W.Duke's paper on the dimension of the space of cusp forms of weight one (see : https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9411212 Lemma 2 p.5).
Take a cuspidal form $f \in \mathcal{S}_1(\Gamma_0(q))$ and let $D$ be a fundamental domain for $\Gamma_0(q)$. The goal is to get an upper-bound on the following integral :
$$I_Y :=\int_{P(Y)} |f(z)|^2y^{-1}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$$
in terms of the Petersson inner product $\langle f,f \rangle$ and where $P(Y)$ is the region afore-defined. Let me explain what I've already figured out for myself.
By noting that the integrand is the actual expression of the Petersson inner product for weight 1 forms, having a finite covering $P(Y) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{r_Y} g_i D$ for some $g_i$'s in $\Gamma_0(q)/\{\pm1\}$ would yield the following :
$$I_Y \leq r_Y \langle f, f \rangle$$
It then boils down to finding $g_i's$ or at least give an upper-bound on $r_Y$. Duke's claim (Lemma 2 p.5  (8)) is that :
$$I_Y \leq \max_{z \in P(Y)} \sharp\{g \in \Gamma_0(q)/\{\pm1\} \mid gz \in P(Y) \} \langle f,f\rangle$$
This is where I'd need some help. Let's call the max in the previous inequality $A$. Note that it follows from the rest of Duke's proof that this $A$ is finite.
If I take some arbitrary $z \in P(Y)$, then the size of the orbit of $\Gamma_0(q)z$ that lies within $P(Y)$ must be at most $A$. Should the integral be a finite sum then one could argue "points in the same orbit appear at most $A$ times hence the inequality" but that is obviously not true here. To get such a bound it seems to me that we would need some statement along these lines :
Take any $z$ in $P(Y)$, if $G_z := \{g \in \Gamma_0(q)/ \{\pm 1\} \mid gz \in P(Y)\}$ then one has a covering $$P(Y) \subset \bigcup_{g \in G_z} gD$$
Now, is that even true ? Or how does Duke's argument even work? I've tried to solve this a couple of times and also asked my supervisor but we couldn't get past it so if anyone knows the exact argument I'm all ears.
